# Toggle div $this without toggling another with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I toggle this divs .pane-content without toggling another with same class?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="pane">
   <div class="pane-header">Settings
  <div class="pane-controls">
        <span class="pane-toggle"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></span>
     <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="pane-content">
         Loreum Ipsum
   </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.pane-toggle').click(function () {
    $('.pane-content').toggle('fast');
    $("i", this).toggleClass("fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  -

```
$('.pane-content',$(this).closest('.pane')).toggle('fast');
```

Demo `----->` http://jsfiddle.net/t5kM7/1/